# Difference between difference between bc547 and 2n2222

Tags: transistors

What is the difference between bc547 and 2n2222A transistor.  I have use bc547 for a project (Water level indicator). Can i use 2n2222A instead of bc547? How each transistors are selected for each project?

Comment: What does comparing the datasheets tell you?

Comment: Trivial questions that only require reading the datasheets should be closed.

Comment: First you should understand how transistors work and what their key parameters are. Then you should learn how to read datasheets in general. Finally you have to compare the datasheets of multiple transistors to determine which one suites your requirements best. Most datasheets provide a list of typical use cases for the component. [Here are _some_ tips on how to read a datasheet](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/66643/17387). [Here too](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/2667/17387). [On transistor basics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/5336/17387)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not much difference when it comes to electrical properties of the two transistors. You can have a look at the datasheets :

- [P2N2222A](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/P2N2222A-D.PDF)
- [BC546/547/548/549/550](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/BC546.pdf)

The two major differences that I find are:

- the power dissipation (a measure of power that transistor can provide):

  2N2222A - 625mW

  BC547 - 500mW
- collector current (output current in common emitter config):

  2N2222A - 600mA

  BC547 - 100mA

So your application defines your selection in such cases. If you need more current amplification for same biasing voltages you might want to go for 2A2222N.

Read the datasheets carefully and make your choice.

Comment: The basic difference is the 2N2222A is explicitly labeled "switching mode transistor", which explains the much higher collector current in the same casing. One has to expect bad linearity and high output capacitance from that. The same part may be labeled B**U**_*nnn* in the Philips scheme.